# SQL query not working in the same way at localhost and AWS

Tags: php, mysql, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

I'm trying to get list of users from a table. So below SQL query results perfect on **localhost** as I wanted but on **AWS** same user repeats several time due to this - **ORDER BY `user_id` DESC** . After removing this from query, it results actual response. So I wanted to know why it behave like this. There are also some PHP functions like (move_uploaded_file()) that works on localhost but failed at AWS.

```
SELECT `user_id` 
FROM `Wo_Users` 
WHERE `user_id` IN (SELECT `following_id` 
                    FROM `Wo_Followers` 
                    WHERE `follower_id` = '1' 
                      AND `following_id` <> '1' 
                      AND `active` = '1') 
AND `active` = '1' 
**ORDER BY `user_id` DESC**
```

Please find attachments below : 
[image]
AWS:
[image]

Comment: Is this GUI being ran on a EC2 instance ?

Comment: Yes, in first example query is running on localhost phpMyAdmin and second one is on AWS phpMyAdmin